# Swift: Counting Swaps in a merge sort

Tags: swift, mergesort

I'm attempting to count swaps in a merge sort. It seemed like a very straightforward proposition, but seem to have a problem with my logic.

Here's the relevant portion of my code where I'm trying to increment my count:

```
    while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        if leftPile[leftIndex] < rightPile[rightIndex] {
            // nothing swapped here
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        } else if leftPile[leftIndex] > rightPile[rightIndex] {
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            // item taken from right pile == swapped -> increment swapCount
            swapCount += 1
            rightIndex += 1
        } else {
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
            // item taken from left pile == swapped -> increment swapCount
            swapCount += 1
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }
    }
```

For some reason, I'm counting 5 swaps with the following array:

```
unsortedArray = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
sortedArray = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
swapCount = 5
```

Here's my full class:

```
class MergeSortWithCounter {

    var swapCount: Int64

    init() {
        swapCount = 0
    }

    func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> [T] {
        guard array.count > 1 else { return array }
        let middleIndex = array.count / 2
        let leftArray = mergeSort(Array(array[0..<middleIndex]))
        let rightArray = mergeSort(Array(array[middleIndex..<array.count]))
        return merge(leftPile: leftArray, rightPile: rightArray)
    }

    func merge<T: Comparable>(leftPile: [T], rightPile: [T]) -> [T] {

        var leftIndex = 0
        var rightIndex = 0
        var orderedPile = [T]()
        if orderedPile.capacity < leftPile.count + rightPile.count {
            orderedPile.reserveCapacity(leftPile.count + rightPile.count)
        }

        while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
            if leftPile[leftIndex] < rightPile[rightIndex] {
                // nothing swapped here
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1
            } else if leftPile[leftIndex] > rightPile[rightIndex] {
                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                // item taken from right pile == swapped -> increment swapCount
                swapCount += 1
                rightIndex += 1
            } else {
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1
                // item taken from left pile == swapped -> increment swapCount
                swapCount += 1
                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                rightIndex += 1
            }
        }

        while leftIndex < leftPile.count {
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        }

        while rightIndex < rightPile.count {
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }

        return orderedPile
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something super simple, but I've spent more time than I care to admit figuring out where my mistake is.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why do think 5 is wrong? (Sorry if I'm being dense but I have no expectations about what the right answer would be. So I am really asking, not criticizing. )

Comment: Also you have a wonderful debugger, so surely you could just step thru the code and see for yourself what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for reading. It is a Hacker Rank test array. They say it's 4. I think my problem lies in the the else statement. I'm not near my machine at the moment, but I'll tinker with it when I'm in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're swapping in the equal case when you don't have to:

```
        if leftPile[leftIndex] < rightPile[rightIndex] {
            // nothing swapped here
```

You meant

```
        if leftPile[leftIndex] <= rightPile[rightIndex] {
            // nothing swapped here
```

Comment: @Pierce I'm having a bit of a challenge with the larger datasets. I'm too cheap to buy a bunch of test cases, but one of the commenters said he used a Long to get around a capacity issue with a vanilla `Int`. That's why I have an `Int64` as my counter. I'll keep you posted when I figure it out all the way. I'm going to put this in an Xcode project, not a playground, to figure it out. There's much going on with the arrays, etc. to troubleshoot without breakpoints.

Comment: @Adrian - I found one main reason why I kept timing out, and that was I forgot to put the `guard` statement at the beginning of `mergeSort`, so it just kept running until it timed out, trying to sort arrays with only one entity. Even after I fixed that I still have problems with half the test cases. Lets see if we can fix this. That specific problem has been driving me crazy by trying to solve with Swift. One other one I had serious problems getting to solve with Swift not timing out was the data structure problem dealing with Tries.